# What should be the public directory for msw initialization when using webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, msw

I had read the [Where is my "public" directory?](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/browser#where-is-my-public-directory) documentation.

> A public directory is usually a root directory of your server (i.e. ./build, ./public, or ./dist). This directory is often committed to Git, and so should be the Mock Service Worker.

I don't think we should commit `./dist` to Git when we use webpack to compile our source code to `output.path: './dist'` directory. This confuses me. I try to integrate `MSW`  in the browser environment.

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: "index_bundle.js",
  },
  mode: "development",
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "./src/index.html" })],
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    port: 9000,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

`src/index.js`:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    const { worker } = require("./mocks/browser");
    worker.start();
  }

  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
};
```

`src/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

`src/mocks/browser.js`:

```js
import { setupWorker } from "msw";
import { handlers } from "./handlers";

export const worker = setupWorker(...handlers);
```

`src/mocks/handlers.js`:

```js
import { rest } from "msw";

export const handlers = [
  rest.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1", (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json({ username: "teresa teng" }));
  }),
];
```

What I had tried below two ways, both of them work when I use `npx webpack serve` command to start webpack dev server and access my application. I got the correct mocked response.

Generate `mockServiceWorker.js` file in `./src/` directory:

```
⚡  npx msw init ./src
```

Overwrite `package.json` with the below content

```json
"msw": {
  "workerDirectory": "src"
}
```

Generate `./dist` directory and `mockServiceWorker.js` file in `./dist/` directory.

```
⚡  npx msw init ./dist
```

But, `./dist/` directory in the `.gitignore` file, which will not commit to Git.

`webpack-dev-server` doesn't write any output files after compiling. Instead, it keeps bundle files in memory. This means there is no real `./dist` directory before `msw` CLI generates it. Besides, the `./dist` file could be deleted in the future for re-compiling.

So, when using `webpack-dev-server` like this, what should the `MSW` initialized public directory be?

Answer (score 1):

When using a custom server setup, like WDS, there's often an option to tell the server which local directory to use for serving static assets.

In the case of WDS, it's the [`devServer.static.directory`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#directory) option. It should point to your *local directory* that you've created to act as a public directory of your website.

```js
$ mkdir public
$ msw init ./public
```

```js
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    static: {
      // Point to the directory you've created.
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    port: 9000
  }
}
```

> You can also point to any other existing directory where you decide to place the worker script.

Verify that the worker script is served correctly by navigating to `http://localhost:9000/mockServiceWorker.js` and seeing the contents of the script file.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but I'll give the answer to someone who needs help:

in your `devServer` config, you have put `dist` directory as the public folder. This is not correct. `dist` is our build path and only exists on production, so `devServer` has nothing to do with it. The default public directory is `<root>/public`.

So you have two ways:

1- move your `index.html` to the `public` folder and remove the configurations of `devServer` (or change the config to use `public` as the static folder). Now you are safe to run ``npx msw init public`.

2- Change your static folder to the root directory.

```
devServer: {
  static: [
    path.resolve(process.cwd())
  ]
}
```

Now you can run `npx msw init .` to have the worker on the root directory.

I suggest the first option as it's cleaner and better maintainable.